# Page redirect upon login

Tags: php

The following script works fine, it allows a user to log in.

After they log in, this line of code requests them to click on a link to go to the members.php page.

```
die("You are now logged in. Please <a href='members.php'>" ."click here</a> to continue.<br /><br />");
```

Is there a way that I can get the page to automatically redirect to members.php after they log in?

```
<?php // login.php
include_once 'header.php';
echo "<div class='main'><h3>Please enter your details to log in</h3>";
$error = $user = $pass = "";

if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
    $pass_hash = md5($pass);

    if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
    {
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM members
            WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass_hash'";

        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
        {
            $error = "<span class='error'>Username/Password
                      invalid</span><br /><br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            die("You are now logged in. Please <a href='members.php'>" . "click here</a> to continue.<br /><br />");
        }
    }
}

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='login.php'>$error
<span class='fieldname'>Username</span><input type='text'
    maxlength='16' name='user' value='$user' /><br />
<span class='fieldname'>Password</span><input type='password'
    maxlength='16' name='pass' value='$pass' />
_END;
?>

<br />
<span class='fieldname'>&nbsp;</span>
<input type='submit' value='Login' />
</form><br /></div></body></html>
```

Comment: There are few ways of doing this. One in particular may give you trouble since you're using sessions and have output above where it should go.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is:

```
header('Location: members.php');
exit;
```

Remember to include the `exit` so that your code stops running even if there is a problem processing the header.

Also note, this needs doing before any output is made whatsoever.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user'])){
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
    $pass_hash = md5($pass);

    if ($user == "" || $pass == ""){
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM members WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass_hash'";
        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0){
            $error = "<span class='error'>Username/Password  invalid</span><br /><br />";
        }else{
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            header('Location: members.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

include_once 'header.php'; //Any output must be after your header code
echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='login.php'>$error
<span class='fieldname'>Username</span><input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user' value='$user' /><br />
<span class='fieldname'>Password</span><input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass' value='$pass' />
_END;
?>

<br />
<span class='fieldname'>&nbsp;</span>
<input type='submit' value='Login' />
</form><br /></div></body></html>
```

BTW - I have not checked any of your code except that which I mention above

Comment: I get this error when I try use that code:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/as1609/public_html/mysite/header.php:3) in /home/as1609/public_html/mysite/login.php on line 32

Comment: As I pointed out, you need to ensure nothing else is output before you send this header. Not even a "space". You will need to move your `echo` on line 3 to elsewhere to start with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Do you think in code? If so, you need debugging. While not here to fully secure and streamline the OP's code, the answers given should point them to the right solution with relevant information to back it all up. What are you trying to say, if anything?

Comment: I removed this line:
echo "<div class='main'><h3>Please enter your details to log in</h3>"
but am still getting the error.  Not sure that else I need to remove to avoid the error.

Comment: The *"not even a space"*. There are too many possible factors at play that could cause this, which is why I never post an answer for questions like these; 9 times out of 10, they open up a can of worms. Other possible factors could be file encoding, a cookie, the session itself, a byte order mark... I can go on. @JBES but I would only fill up this comment space.

Comment: Ignore Fred. Canadian beer must be good ;) Put the answer code in place of your `die(...`. I will modify the answer now...

Comment: We've got some of the finest breweries around, but don't be so presumptuous; I don't touch the stuff myself ;-) Don't forget to make a mention about `mysql_*` and MD5 now ;-) Ticking timebombs must be handled with care.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I highly recommend a nice cold beer, nothing better in my opinion. Why would you pass on such delights? Anyway, S.O. is a game of points. Pleased to make your acquaintance.

Comment: I will admit that I was in it for the points some time ago, but I also genuinely enjoy helping people out with solutions; it also helps me to better my skills at troubleshooting/debugging, not to mention writing faster code. I noticed in your profile that you programmed in Assembler (cool); I learned some of it way back in the early 90's including Turbo Pascal and C+, but PHP/SQL are what I enjoy most now. I'm equally pleased to make your acquaintance as well, and as we also say around here; cheers ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, of course, points mean nothing ultimately - a 'virtual' reward worth nothing. I do actively program in assembler because I quite like its power and speed. Anything using logic is good, for me. I also maintain the opinion that, of the few I have known, Canadians are some of the nicest people in the World. You are no exception. Cheers. Enough of hijacking this thread though...

Comment: No more thread hijacking, just wanted to say thanks. We can be a strange animal at times, but that's just a little quirk ;-) cheers.

Comment: Problem is that the "include_once 'header.php'" line you moved to the bottom 1) calls in many functions that are required for this page, 2) has code that ensures the user is logged in and 3) inserts the header.  

So it has to be at the top.  I never knew a simple page redirect could be such a fussy piece of code, lol!

Comment: In this case, consider moving the code here to your header.php and integrate it properly there as you require it. I assume the redirect would still be needed as it is a global login procedure.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you have the die() line, you can do this

```
ob_clean();
header('Location: http://www.example.com');
exit;
```

Comment: `ob_clean`? Also, your code won't run. You are missing an apostrophe.

Comment: I get this error when I try use that code:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/as1609/public_html/mysite/header.php:3) in /home/as1609/public_html/mysite/login.php on line 32

Answer (score 0):

If headers are giving you a hard time, you can use this alternate (*meta*) method:

Where you presently have `die("You are now logged in...` do:

```
echo "You are not logged in. You will be redirected in 5 seconds...";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=http://www.yoursite.com/members.php>";
```

Sidenote: Replace the `5` in `content=5` with the amount of seconds you wish to take for the redirection. Using `0` will redirect right away.

It's not the best method but it works in many instances.

Another method is to add [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/ob_start) under your opening `<?php` tag which works at times.

Example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// login.php
include_once 'header.php';
echo "<div class='main'><h3>Please enter your details to log in</h3>";
$error = $user = $pass = "";

...

$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            // die("You are now logged in....

    // keep the http:// and replace with your website address
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/members.php');
    exit;

...
```